# Is there any chance audio can be recovered from a video recording which appears in QuickTime and other apps to have no audio track?

Tags: audio, data-recovery, quicktime, webcam, video-capture

Running macOS 10.12 with a security app called EvoCam that records ".mov" MP4 files. It records in one hour segments using the built-in iSight camera and microphone.

In one hour long segment the audio cut out. And then in the subsequent videos, there is no audio at all.

When I open them in QuickTime, it does not mention there being an audio track. I also tried opening them in VLC with no luck.

I am not sure what happened as there was no error message and the microphone is working. Quitting the app and restarting it caused it to start recording audio again.

Is there any chance the audio is in the file but corrupted and might be salvageable? I have found some services that do video repair and I even opened the video file in one such service's app. It's an app called Treasured. However, that service's app didn't say it found audio, just H264 video.

This is an older Mac set up for security purposes, and the audio is very important if it can be recovered--would be willing to pay for a service or app that could recover it, but I'm not even sure if it's possible that it's there. This did happen once before and the same thing (quitting and reopening the app) worked, but the audio wasn't important in that instance.

Comment: I have the Console log if that helps--I tried posting it here, but it is far too long to fit in a comment, and I'm not sure which parts would be important, but this is what fits:

default 2022-06-10 11:42:39.321666 -0400 kernel +-IOAudioEngine[<private>]::beginConfigurationChange()
default 2022-06-10 11:42:39.322672 -0400 kernel +- IOAudioEngine[<private>]::completeConfigurationChange()
default 2022-06-10 11:42:39.323341 -0400 kernel + IOAudioEngineUserClient::externalMethod, selector=0x4,   arg0 0x0, arg1 0x0, arg2 0x0 arg3 0x0

Comment: There were a lot more messages from coreaudiod, but here is where EvoCam showsup:

default 2022-06-10 11:42:39.332226 -0400 EvoCam HALB_MachPort.cpp:277:SendMessage:  HALB_MachPort::SendMessage: mach_msg() returned error 0x10000003: '(ipc/send) invalid destination port'
default 2022-06-10 11:42:39.332229 -0400 EvoCam HALC_ProxyIOContext.cpp:1399:IOWorkLoop:  HALC_ProxyIOContext::IOWorkLoop: failed to send the final message to the server, Error: 0x10000003
default 2022-06-10 11:42:39.332439 -0400 SiriNCService Error: 0, AHS_UserSettings::CanBeDefaultDevice: got an error from the HAL when

Comment: For the future have two machines both doing recording separately and even a third doing just audio if it is that important.